# COM Enabled .NET User Control

Tags: c#, deployment, user-controls, regasm

I have created a COM enabled .NET User Control and am wondering what is the best way to deploy this to users to use the control in a web page ?

Is cab the way to go with this ? I understand that I will need to regasm the control on the user's machine. 
Would a regular msi be better and easier to use for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to register a .net assembly if it's hosted on a web server, you can just use the overloaded `<OBJECT>` tag:

```
<OBJECT id="Obj1" classid="Assembly.dll#Full.Namespace.ControlName">
```

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317346:

> This usage is very powerful, because .NET assemblies install by using the new zero-impact Fusion technology, which enables assembly installation without the need to write any secondary information to the user's registry. To update the control is as simple as downloading a new copy (which the Runtime takes care of automatically); removing it from the computer is as simple as removing the assembly from the Fusion download cache.

Also see: [How To: Deploy COM Interop Programs to Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311297)